# Showing muptiple components in an app by vue3

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I made two components and tried to show these in vue3 app.

my code in html

```
<div id="app">
    <image_preview>
        URL: [[image]]
    </image_preview>
    <file_uploader>
       Counter:[[counter]]
    </file_uploader>
</div>
```

in javascript

```
const ImagePreview = {
    data(){
        return {
            image:"test.png"
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    },   
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]']  
}
const Counter = {
    data() {
      return{counter: 0}
    },
    mounted() {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.counter++
      }, 1000)
    },
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]']  
  }

Vue.createApp({
    components:{
        "image_preview":ImagePreview,
        "file_uploader":Counter
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

However nothing appears in html

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you see error messages in the console? Have you looked at it with [Vue Developer tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd)? Helps me a lot usually. Does it work with other components or simple HTML tags?

Comment: Should the ImagePreview have props, and the image url passed into via the prop name attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please re-read vue's documentation on components you know if you're going to need a template to render components and I bet you haven't read vue's documentation on components

follow my example and it takes care of your problem:

```js
// </script><script type="module">
import { createApp, ref, onMounted } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js'


const ImagePreview = {
  template: '#image_preview',
  setup() {
    return {
      image: 'test.png'
    }
  }
}
const Counter = {
  template: '#file_uploader',
  setup() {
    const counter = ref(0)
    
    onMounted(() => setInterval(() => counter.value++, 1_000))
    
    return { counter }
  }
}

const app = createApp({
  components:{
    "image_preview": ImagePreview,
    "file_uploader": Counter
  }
})
.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <image_preview>
        URL: [[image]]
    </image_preview>
    <file_uploader>
       Counter:[[counter]]
    </file_uploader>
</div>

<template id="image_preview">
  URL: {{ image }}
</template>

<template id="file_uploader">
  Counter: {{ counter }}
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it solve my problem and help me to learn more.